# Can a value of a database field be used as a program statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store "formulas" in a MySQL database.

Such an expression could be `"$cY+1.5*$X;"`.

Is there a possibility to let the VARCHAR variable in the database table be "translated" into a PHP program statement so I could write

```
$formula = 'value of the VARCHAR variable'
```

Comment: [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: ^- Yes, eval(), but this is a very bad practice.

Comment: This is such a bad idea from security perspective, not to mention maintainability.

Comment: I would NOT recommend using `eval` @MonkeyZeus

Comment: If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'll replace the variables with tokens like this :

```
"{{cY}}+1.5*{{X}};
```

You could use preg_replace to replace the tokens with values.
But i'm not sure is that you are looking for.

Comment: To be more clear... Think of the problem as a copy & paste situation: I want to copy the VARCHAR value and paste it in the PHP-code as the right side of a PHP assignment statement! That is create/manipulate the PHP source-code itself!!! OK?

Comment: As they commented to your question, you want to eval the content of a string.
Which is not recommended.

There seems to be some PHP Library that does the parsing of formulas :
https://packagist.org/packages/webit/eval-math